# AngularJS: $defer.resolve() not binding data to table

Tags: angularjs, deferred, ngtable

Below is my HTML code for loading data in a table.

```
<table id="users" class="dashboard-widget msbf-table" ng-table="usersTableParams" hide-pagination="false" show-filter="true">
                    <tr ng-repeat = "user in users" ng-click="usersClicked($event, user.userId);">
                        <td data-title="'User login'" sortable="'userLogin'" filter="{'userId' : 'text'}">{{user.userId}}</td>
                        <td data-title="'User role'" sortable="" filter="{'roleName' : 'text'}">{{user.roleName}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

This is my code for populating data in the table:

```
$scope.usersTableParams = new ngTableParams({
            page: startPage,
            count: rowsPerPage,
            sorting: {
                userId: 'asc'
            },
            filter: {
                userId: '',
                roleName:''
            }
        },
        {
            total: $scope.users.length,
            getData: function($defer, params){
                 // use build-in angular filter
                var orderedData = getFilteredSortedData($scope.users, params);
                //var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.users, params.filter()) : $scope.users;
                //$scope.users = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

                params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination


                $defer.resolve(getSlicedData(orderedData,params));
            }
        });

var getFilteredSortedData = function(data, params) {
            if (params.filter()) {
                data = $filter('filter')(data, params.filter());
            }
            if (params) {
                data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(data, params.orderBy()) : data;
            }
            console.log('Filtered Data: '+JSON.stringify(data));
            console.log('Filtered Data size: '+data.length);
            return data;
        };
        //slices the data for the current page, checked
        var getSlicedData = function(data, params) {
             var slicedData = data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
             console.log('Sliced Data: '+JSON.stringify(slicedData));
             console.log('Sliced Data size: '+data.length);
             return slicedData;
        };
```

The problem is that the data is coming correctly to the variable 'slicedData', however, this doesn't get's populated in the HTML table. What I suspect is that the line :

```
$defer.resolve(getSlicedData(orderedData,params))'
```

is not working. Any pointers / idea are welcome.

Thanks & Regards
Nishant Kumar

Comment: what's `$defer` here? is it out of angular context that you need to `$apply` ?

Comment: $defer is the promise object used for resolving the dependencies and rendering the final data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going wrong.

```
<table id="users" class="dashboard-widget msbf-table" ng-table="usersTableParams" hide-pagination="false" show-filter="true">
                <tr ng-repeat = "user in users" ng-click="usersClicked($event, user.userId);">
                    ....
                </tr>
            </table>
```

The

```
ng-repeat = "user in users"
```

should be replaced with

```
ng-repeat = "user in $data"
```

if you are using

```
getData in ngTableParams
```

to customize your data that is being displayed.

Based on my understanding, this happens because the getData() function puts data with all other details in $data rather than the variable that actually stores it. This $data variable is responsible for data that will be rendered based on configurations specified for the table when declaring the parameters for the table.
Hope you all concur with my understanding. Since I am new to Angular JS, so I might have provided explanation based on wrong assumptions so corrections of any sort are most welcome and thanks to all StackFlow followers and contributors for helping me out here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call $apply, or trigger a digest after the resolve is called.

Change getData to be:

```
getData: function($defer, $timeout, params){
     // use build-in angular filter
    var orderedData = getFilteredSortedData($scope.users, params);
    //var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.users, params.filter()) : $scope.users;
    //$scope.users = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

    params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination


    $defer.resolve(getSlicedData(orderedData,params));
    if (!$scope.$$phase) {
        $scope.$digest();
    }
}
```

You could also try wrapping $defer.resolve in a $timeout, this triggers a digest - Try this:

```
getData: function($defer, params){
     // use build-in angular filter
    var orderedData = getFilteredSortedData($scope.users, params);
    //var orderedData = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.users, params.filter()) : $scope.users;
    //$scope.users = orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());

    params.total(orderedData.length); // set total for recalc pagination


    $timeout(function() {
        $defer.resolve(getSlicedData(orderedData,params));
    })
}
```

The reason you need to do this is asnychronous code is not picked up by angularJS's watchers.

Comment: From where will I get the $timeout module?

Comment: It's a part of angularJS, you need to inject it into the controller (like you did $scope)

Comment: I tried all that but none is working. I wonder what is going wrong.